# Cannot update a MutableStateFlow backed by Room

Tags: android, kotlin-flow

Before switching to Room, I was using a Repository backed by static data. Everything was working as expected. I updated `selectedCategory` from Composables without any problem, which then helped me to navigate to the full path made of `selectedCategory` and `selectedItem`. Then I switched to Room and all hells broke loose. Parts of the code seem to be never executed inside the ViewModel because no logs are pushed to console.

The code:

```kotlin
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.droidcon.deeplinksnav.data.CategoryRepository
import com.droidcon.deeplinksnav.data.local.database.Category
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class CategoryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val categoryRepository: CategoryRepository
    ): ViewModel() {

    val uiState: StateFlow<CategoryUiState> = categoryRepository
        .categories.map<List<Category>, CategoryUiState>(CategoryUiState::Success)
        .catch { emit(CategoryUiState.Error(it)) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), CategoryUiState.Loading)

    private val _selectedCategory = MutableStateFlow<Category?>(value = null)

    /**
     * Keeps track of the current selected category from the category grid
     */
    val selectedCategory: StateFlow<Category?>
        get() = _selectedCategory

    fun addCategory(category: Category) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            categoryRepository.add(category)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the selected category to the category with the name [categoryName]
     */
    fun updateSelectedCategoryByName(categoryName: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val search = categoryRepository.getCategoryByName(categoryName)
            Log.d("CategoryViewModel", "updateSelectedCategoryByName: Found category: ${search?.name}")
            search?.let{category->
                _selectedCategory.value = category

                //TODO: Fix needed
                selectedCategory.collect{
                    delay(500)
                    Log.d("CategoryViewModel", "updateSelectedCategoryByName: current selected category: ${selectedCategory.value?.name}")
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

sealed interface CategoryUiState {
    data object Loading : CategoryUiState
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : CategoryUiState
    data class Success(val data: List<Category>) : CategoryUiState
}
```

Interestingly, `selectedCategory` never seems to be updated. The log statement inside collect{} block is not executed at all and logging the following value under a `composable` node shows it is null, no matter if I have called `viewModel.updateSelectedCategoryByName()` before logging it:

```kotlin
    val selectedCategory by categoryViewModel.selectedCategory.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

Answer (score 0):

Poor Room had nothing to do with this bug. The problem was that I was using a stupid method to search for repository items based on name:

```kotlin
    override suspend fun getCategoryByName(name: String): Category? {
        var category: Category? = null
        categoryDao.getCategories().collect { list ->
            category = list.find { category ->
                val processedName = category.name.filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }.lowercase()
                val nameToTest = name.filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }.lowercase()
                nameToTest == processedName
            }
        }
        return category

}
```

which didn't work probably due to the asynchronous unfathomable nature of Kotlin flow. Looks like the collect block never succeeded or something. I would appreciate if someone clarifies on this.

The issue was fixed when I replaced the above code with:

```kotlin
    override suspend fun getCategoryByName(name: String): Category? {
        return categories.first().find {category ->
            category.name.filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }.lowercase() == name.filterNot { it.isWhitespace() }.lowercase()
        }
    }
```